# How to check if object is null or not except == null

Tags: java, null

I want to make method that will check if the class instance is null or not.

Simply I know that i can use `== null`, but I want to know that is there any other way that can be implemented to check if instance is null or not ?

I have nearly `70-80` class instance. & all that class extend same Class `BaseEntity`.

at time of declaration I have declare each instance like :

Entity1 instance1 = null;

like so I have defined all `70 class instances`.

when they will be used I am initializing them using new.
but at end of my main `Entity Processor`, I have to store data of each Entity id it is initialized, so for that I ll have to check if instance is null or not ?

`All Entities extend` same class `BaseEntity` so I have made following method.

I know only one method :

```
public boolean checkIfEntityNull(BaseEntity entity){
        return  entity != null ? true : false;
}
```

if it returns `true` then I ll call it's `save method of repository to save data in DB` otherwise it ll not call save method.

So any guidance on it guys.

Comment: Side note: `return entity != null ? true : false;` can be reduced to `return entity != null;`

Comment: To be honest, i dont know what you are making if you require 70 variables in a class ( would an ArrayList<BaseEntity> not be better?)
But apart from that, what is wrong with the == comparison? also, i would write that method:
public boolean checkIfEntityNull(Object entity){
        return  entity != null;
}

Comment: @BackSlash : I have reduced that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest way to check is `entity == null`. There is no shorter way to do that.

Note that there is a method for this in the standard lib:

[Objects.isNull(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-)

And another one which is the opposite of the above one:

[Objects.nonNull(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-)

And there is yet another one which can be used to force a value to be not `null`, it throws a `NullPointerException` otherwise:

[T Objects.requireNonNull(T obj);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-)

**Note:** The [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class was added in Java 7, but the `isNull()` and `nonNull()` methods were added only in Java 8.

Comment: I would also mention that these methods were introduced with Java 8, so if you are using an older version you won't have them.

Comment: yes I am using `Java 7 update 67` so i can't use them.

Comment: They were introduced in **Java 7** so you **can** use them.

Comment: @icza Are you sure The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) doesn't have these methods, it just has the `requireNonNull`.

Comment: You're right, `Objects` was added in Java 7 but the mentioned first 2 methods were added in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

try this using reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ObjectsUtils {
    public static boolean allNull(Object target) {
        return Arrays.stream(target.getClass()
                .getDeclaredFields())
            .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true))
            .map(f -> getFieldValue(f, target))
            .allMatch(Objects::isNull);
    }

    private static Object getFieldValue(Field field, Object target) {
        try {
            return field.get(target);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```