# What is the best way to check object and it's members are null in Java

Tags: java, java-8, nullable

Have this piece of code:

```
Class X {
    Map< Y, Z> mapFromNameToZObjects;
}
```

I want to check if X and the map are null.
Currently I have the following:

```
private checkFunction(X x) {
  If (x == null || x.getMap.isNullOrEmpty) { 
      throw some Exception
   }
}
```

Wondering if there is a prettier way to check it.

Comment: That code that you show does not compile, so we don't know what you're doing. What is `isNullorEmpty`? A field? A method?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Optional` with it's `filter` and `map` methods :

```
private void checkFunction(X x) throws Exception {
    Optional.ofNullable(x)
            .map(X::getMap)
            .filter(map -> !map.isEmpty())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception()); // your exception here

  //...
}
```

Comment: this is not "prettier" IMO this is more complex, harder to maintain and harder to understand, also you are adding the overhead of `Optional` unnecessary instance creation. Pretty code = code that is simple and easy to maintain, Pretty code != code using lambda.

Answer (score 1):

By using `Optional.ofNullable()` and `Optional.map()`

```java
public static class X<K, V>{
    Map<K, V> mapFromNameToZObjects;
    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return mapFromNameToZObjects;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    X<String, String> x = new X<>();

    Optional<Map<String, String>> optionalMap = Optional.ofNullable(x).map(X::getMap);

    boolean allNull = !(optionalMap.isPresent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code it yourself.

`if (x == null || x.isEmpty())`

If already using the [apache collections library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4).

`if (MapUtils.isEmpty(x))`

Answer (score 0):

If the object is null then it doesn't have any members, so you cannot have the object and its members null at the same time.

If you want to check if either the object or its field is null then you can use:

```
    if (x == null || x.getMap() == null) {
        // throw exception
    }
```

If you want to also check its map is empty(it doesn't contain any key-value mappings) then you can use:

```
    if (x == null || x.getMap() == null || x.getMap().isEmpty()) {
        // throw exception
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to check is entity == null. There is no shorter way to do that.

Note that there is a method for this in the standard lib:

```
Objects.isNull(Object obj)
```

And another one which is the opposite of the above one:

```
Objects.nonNull(Object obj)
```

And there is yet another one which can be used to force a value to be not null, it throws a NullPointerException otherwise:

```
T Objects.requireNonNull(T obj);
```

Note: The Objects class was added in Java 7, but the isNull() and nonNull() methods were added only in Java 8. Ref :[How to check if object is null or not except == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642585/how-to-check-if-object-is-null-or-not-except-null)

Comment: You just copy pasted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642884/5168011)